# Connecting to a database with MySQLdb in python

Tags: python, mysql

So Basically I was just trying to test this out:

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="myhost.com",    user="myusername", passwd="mypassword", db="nameofmydatabase")

query = "INSERT INTO nameofmydatabase (columntitle) values ('sampletext')"
x = conn.cursor()
x.execute(query)
row = x.fetchall()
```

So this is the error that I got. I changed my actual info in the error but I was wondering how to fix this.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "write2MySQL_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="myhost.com", user="myusername", passwd="mypassword", db="nameofmydatabase")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 193, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on  'myhost.com' (60)")
```

Comment: is your mysql daemon accessible from the outside world directly if on a host, or is it rightly hidden

Comment: Are you sure you are attempting to connect to the correct port?

Comment: How do I specify the port in python?

Comment: Using MySQLdb... I guess that is what I will lookup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried connecting to your MySQL database manually? (Using PhpMyAdmin or MySQL query browser etc) 
Are you able to reach the database from teh machine you are running the code on ? Ping the ip to see if there is a firewall.

Also, I am not sure how you set it up, is myhost.com pointing to something? Did you mean localhost?

Edit-

Try using your port like this

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host = 'localhost', 
    user = 'root', 
    passwd = '', 
    db = 'dbname', 
    port = 3306)
```

I am not sure if your database is called "nameofmydatabase" so please make sure you fill the fields appropriately.

Comment: I can connect to my database using my desktop application Sequel Pro

Comment: I type in the exact same credentials that i have in the python program

Comment: In addition I also specify the port 3306. Could it be that I need to specify the port in the python program

Answer (score 0):

Host Name is wrong you can use "localhost" in place of "myhost.com".
I have created a sample Class for connecting and querying from Db.

You can use below code to connect to Database.
Change the value of uname, passwd and Database Name

```
import MySQLdb
class DbFunctions(object):
    def _ _init_ _(self,server,uname,passwd,dbname):
        self.server = server
        self.uname = uname
        self.passwd = passwd
        self.dbname = dbname
        self.db = None
        self.cur = None

    def connection_open(self):
        self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host=self.server,user=self.uname,passwd=self.password,db=self.dbname)
        self.cur = self.db.cursor()

    def connection_close(self):
        self.db.close()

    def mysql_qry(self,sql,bool): # 1 for select and 0 for insert update delete
        self.connection_open()
        try:
            self.cur.execute(sql)
            if bool:
                return self.cur.fetchall()
            else:
                self.db.commit()
                return True
        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            try:
                print "Mysql Error:- "+str(e)
            except IndexError:
                print "Mysql Error:- "+str(e)
        self.connection_close()

    def mysql_insert(self,table,fields,values):
        sql = "INSERT INTO " + table + " (" + fields + ") VALUES (" + values + ")";
        return self.mysql_qry(sql,0)

    def mysql_update(self,table,values,conditions):
        sql = "UPDATE " + table + " SET " + values + " WHERE " + conditions
        return self.mysql_qry(sql,0)

    def mysql_delete(self,table,condtions):
        sql = "DELETE FROM " + table + " WHERE " + condition;
        return self.mysql_qry(sql,0)

    def mysql_select(self,table):
        sql =  "SELECT * FROM "+table
        return self.mysql_qry(sql,1)
```

`db = DbFunctions("localhost","uname","passwd","database_name")

You can check out below link of my github account for more details
https://github.com/pantlavanya/codes/blob/master/db_function_library.py